# Spring Security Filter order per url

Tags: java, spring-security, filter

I have two filters that process my httpRequest and adds headers and data.

I want to apply my filters in a certain order of execution. So I ve tried :

```
@Component
@Order(1)
public class FirstFilter implements Filter { //**** }

@Component
@Order(2)
public class SecondFilter implements Filter { //**** }
```

and This works fine. However I want to apply this order only to request that starts with (/api) and not to all request.. so the @Order annotation is not doing what I want to..

I've tried :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

http

        .antMatcher("/api/**")
        .addFilterAfter(new FirstFilter (), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(new SecondtFilter (), FirstFilter .class)
```

and this works too, but I didnt like to add my filters after the ChannelProcessingFilter .. this makes requests to be processed two times by my filters! and not only one time!

Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe try a [OncePerRequestFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html)?

Comment: Your question is unclear. The way it's phrased makes it sound like you want the *order* of the filters to be URL-dependent, but it seems more like you want the filters *themselves* to to be URL-dependent. Please edit and clarify.

Comment: You question is not clear. 1. *I want to apply this order only to request that starts with (/api)* Do you want to change the order for other URLs or do you want to remove the filters for other URLs at all? 2. *but I didnt like to add my filters after the ChannelProcessingFilter* You could also add them before, if that is your question. 3. *this makes requests to be processed two times* The order has nothing to do that your filters are executed twice.

Answer (score 0):

Read [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1640) issue detail which is exactly what you are asking. It readout

> Spring Security doesn't set an order on the Filter bean that it
>   creates. This means that, when Boot is creating a
>   FilterRegistrationBean for it, it gets the default order which is
>   LOWEST_PRECEDENCE.
>
> If you want your own Filter to go after Spring Security's you can
>   create your own registration for Spring Security's filter and specify
>   the order.

Answer (score 0):

You must override this method in your filter:

```kotlin
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        RequestMatcher uriMatcher = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/some/url", HttpMethod.GET.name());
        RequestMatcher matcher = new NegatedRequestMatcher(uriMatcher);
        return matcher.matches(request);
    }
```